# Translating text to Morse , not sure how to achieve required output

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

Need to translate text to Morse for an assignment.
The outputted format of the Morse needs to be like this ".../---/... "space" .../---/..."
With a space in between words , and a / in between characters. However the / cannot be at the beginning or end of word.
Mine outputs like this " .../---/.../ "space" /.../---/.../ " Obviously failing.
I am sure there is a simple fix but I seem to be having a meltdown, Please help.

```
// Morse alphabet array 
String  morse [28] = {

  ".-",
  "-...",
  "-.-.",
  "-..",
  ".",
  "..-.",
  "--.",
  "....",
  "..",
  ".---",
  "-.-",
  ".-..",
  "--",
  "-.",
  "---",
  ".--.",
  "--.-",
  ".-.",
  "...",
  "-",
  "..-",
  "...-",
  ".--",
  "-..-",
  "-.--",
  "--..",
  " "
};
// Alphabet array 
char letters [27] = {

  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e',
  'f',
  'g',
  'h',
  'i',
  'j',
  'k',
  'l',
  'm',
  'n',
  'o',
  'p',
  'q',
  'r',
  's',
  't',
  'u',
  'v',
  'w',
  'x',
  'y',
  'z',
  ' '

};

// Translates a text char to a morse char
String char2Morse (char a) {
  
  int b = tolower (a);
  for (int index = 0; index < 28; index ++) {
    if (  b == (letters [index])) {
      return (morse [index]);
     }
  }
}


// Translates a text string into Morse
String  word2Morse (String wordy) {
  String  returnstring = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < wordy.length (); i ++) {
     
    returnstring += (char2Morse (wordy[i]));
     returnstring += ('/');
   }
   return returnstring ;
  }
```

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: I do know about the debugger. But I am afraid its nothing wrong with my code , I simply don't know how to only implement the slash in between characters and not at the start and end of the word. So in this case its my lack of knowledge that is the problem. This is my first assignment ever.

Comment: Well, try this: take a blank sheet of paper and write down using short, brief sentences, in clear English, a detailed explanation of how the shown code is expected to work, one step a time, in order to produce the expected results. Write it down so that the logical process, in black on white, is clear, straightforward, and is obviously correct. Then, take the paper, set it to one side, on the other side run the debugger, step by step. The debugger should display the same results as what's on the paper. At the point where the debugger shows something different, that must be the problem.

Comment: The computer is only doing what you told it to do. If you don't want a slash after every letter, then don't tell the computer to unconditionally put a slash after every letter.

Comment: *Hmm...* Here's a way to simplify things that might help: don't translate into Morse code. Take your input `sos sos` and transform it into `s/o/s s/o/s`. That will give you fewer complications to worry about, and you can add your translation back in once you get this part worked out.

Comment: I'm not sure how to change it so that it only puts a slash after every letter except the end of a word  , perhaps an operator that i don't know ?

Comment: Sure i could try that

Comment: Quick thing, one is `morse` `[28]`, instead of 27?

Comment: Try changing `returnstring += ('/');` to `if (i != wordy.length() - 1) returnstring += ('/');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to understand when exactly you would need to add a `/` after the character. Currently, inside the for loop of `word2Morse`, you are adding `/` after translating every character.

However, you actually don't want `/` before or after an word. However, you can't tell the program to not put a slash before or after an word, because it doesn't know what is a word. Instead you need to find a simpler logic.

---

Imagine you are trying to translate the word: **`hello world`**

You are doing fine translating the first 5 character. However, without any changes to your code, you will add a slash right after the first `o`, which is not what you want.

But why don't you want a slash after `o`? Because it is the end of a word. And how do you know that? It's because the next character is a space.

Now, that's a logic you can explain: ***You don't want a slash if the next character is a space!***

So go back to your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordy.length (); i ++) {
    returnstring += (char2Morse (wordy[i]));
    returnstring += ('/');
}
```

You can add that logic before you add `/` to your string:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordy.length (); i ++) {
    returnstring += (char2Morse (wordy[i]));
    if (wordy[i+1] != ' ') {
        returnstring += ('/');
    }
}
```

Now, you will never add a slash if there's a space after your current character.

---

However, you will have similar problem after the space, and before the letter `w`. But once again, you can form a similar logic here: ***You don't want a slash if your current character is a space!***

This time I will **not** write the code out, because it should be your homework. But the essence would be to add more boolean test in that if statement.

---

However, there is one more thing to watchout, which is when you are approaching the end of the sentence. Once you have translated the last character `d`, it would once again try to check if the next character is a space. However, you do not have another character afterwards. And trying to check it will end in errors. So in that if statement, you also want to check you are not at the last character!

---

One other thing to note is that you probably don't want to write out something like:

```cpp
char letters [27] = {
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
   ⋮
   ⋮
```

It's way too repetitive, don't you think? Instead, say if `myChar` is `'g'` , you can get a number by doing `myChar - 'a'`, which would give you `6`.

So for most of the `char2Morse`, you can do it like:

```cpp
String char2Morse(char a) {
    char lower_a = tolower (a);
    return morse[lower_a - 'a'];
}
```

The only thing to catch here is that you can't do it with the space character, which can be tested out with a if-statement:

```cpp
String char2Morse(char a) {
    if (a == ' ') {
        return morse[27];
    }
    else {
        return morse[tolower(a) - 'a'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's got it now , i did not realize you could do [i + 1] and have it still compile. I knew it would be something simple, but still getting used to a lot of the syntax.

Comment: @chazser22 No problem. I also added a part about your `char2Morse` function, in case you were interested.

Comment: Be careful of using `i+1`. The approach is valid for a `std::string` since `std::string s` has a null-terminator at `s[s.size()]`. However, the question uses `String`, not `std::string`, and alternative string implementations are not required to have this property; accessing `wordy[i+1]` might be undefined behavior in the final iteration.